# Why a common Trumpet is in B flat pitch ?

Tags: trumpet

Why is Trumpet mentioned as B flat pitch ? How it becomes suitable for C scale ?

Comment: Related: [What are the practical reasons for still having transposing instruments?](http://music.stackexchange.com/questions/7225/what-are-the-practical-reasons-for-still-having-transposing-instruments)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first question already has an answer. The second is that one plays the notes in the key of D on the music, which come out sounding as if they belong to the C scale.