# Why is sheet music for guitar different from piano

Tags: guitar, piano, notation

Why is middle C on guitar music played an octave lower in pitch on guitar than on piano? I can play guitar while reading from piano music on the grand staff with middle C at concert, and it's not any more difficult to read, ledger lines become the bass clef, and there are less ledger lines used above the treble clef when done this way. Is there another reason?

Comment: Typically to avoid forcing players to read so many ledger lines. Check out https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/7225/what-are-the-practical-reasons-for-still-having-transposing-instruments and https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/5374/what-is-a-transposing-instrument

Answer (score 1):

Having the guitar notated as pitched would cause the use of many ledger lines.

It is transposed simply for convenience sake to make it easier to read for the player.