# Is my trumpet sound shifted?

Tags: tuning, fingering, trumpet

I am new to trumpet, bought one recently and here's what I found:

The trumpet looks like `Bb` kind:
[image: Looks like it is a Bb trumpet]

I googled `Bb trumpet fingerings` (e.g. [this](https://www.justforbrass.com/skins/quill/just_for_brass/assets/images/site/charts/JustForBrass-Trumpet-Fingering-Chart.pdf)) and they all say that all open valves (and lowest note) should give me `C` note.

However, the *lowest* note on *all open walves* on my trumpet sound `Bb`, I checked it with the piano.

So the question is: what am I doing wrong? Is that the trumpet or my bad playing?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Don't worry, everything is as expected.

Trumpet is a transposing instrument. If you play the note that a trumpeter would call 'C', it's really a Bb. We say that a trumpet is written a major second higher than it sounds.

You're not the first person to be confused by this. If you search for terms like 'transposing instrument' and 'concert pitch', you'll find out a lot more information. There's various historical and practical reasons why this is the case.

Some very quick examples I found on this topic:

[Could B♭ instruments be built in C? Why are they in B♭ in the first place?](https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/7734/could-b-instruments-be-built-in-c-why-are-they-in-b-in-the-first-place)

[Why do instruments have a key?](https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/44276/why-do-instruments-have-a-key)

[What is a transposing instrument?](https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/5374/what-is-a-transposing-instrument)

[Trumpet - Should I think in concert pitch or not?](https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/57001/trumpet-should-i-think-in-concert-pitch-or-not)

[Which tone names should I learn on a transposing instrument like a saxophone?](https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/27432/which-tone-names-should-i-learn-on-a-transposing-instrument-like-a-saxophone)